# Assign a knockout observable value from remote source

Tags: knockout.js

I have the following knockout viewmodel:

```
function DepartmentsViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.currentComplaint = ko.observable('');
    self.departments = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.selectedDepartment = ko.observable('').extend({
        required: true
    });

}
```

I then populate my departments and assign the `selectedDepartment` value with a series of remote calls to my Controller (`id` is just a number I assign to a variable based on the current page the user is at):

```
$(function() {
    var self = new DepartmentsViewModel();

    self.currentComplaint(id);

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetDepartments")',
        success: function (data) {
            self.departments(data);
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetDetails")',
        data: { id: id },
        success: function (data) {
            self.selectedDepartment(data.DepartmentId);
        }
    });

    ko.applyBindings(self);

});
```

This is then populated in my HTML like so:

```
<select class="complaint-select" 
        data-bind="options: departments, 
                   optionsText: function(item) { 
                       return item.DepartmentCode + ' - ' + item.DepartmentName 
                   }, 
                   optionsValue: 'DepartmentId',
                   value: selectedDepartment, 
                   optionsCaption: 'Choose..'">
</select>
```

I notice that sometimes my `selectedDepartment` doesn't get set when I refresh my page, and as a result, my dropdown doesn't have any value set and tells me to select an option from the dropdown? Any idea as to why? I've done a `console.log(self.selectedDepartment());` on the `complete` action of my AJAX request and sometimes it is set, but others it is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of making separete ajax calls you have to chain these ajax calls to make sure that there is always valid deparmantList exist in your departmantArray for any given id. Because the result's of ajax calls came randomly you cant be sure which one is come first.

```
var departmantLoadProcess =  $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetDepartments")'      
});

departmantLoadProcess.done(function(data){

    self.departments(data);

    var detailLoadProcess = $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetDetails")',
        data: { id: id },
        success: function (data) {         
        }
    });

    detailLoadProcess.done(function(data){
       self.selectedDepartment(data.DepartmentId);
    });

});
```

For more information inspect Jquery [deferred object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)

**EDIT:**

Just like Ryan mentioned serilazing ajax requests cause some overload if we get millions hit :) and we dont need to wait them if their result's doesnt depend on eachother. We can optimize it further.

```
// If both ajax request success

$.when( $.ajax({url: '@Url.Action("GetDepartments")'}),
        $.ajax({url: '@Url.Action("GetDetails")' , data : {id:id}}) ).done(function(deparmantsData,detailsData) {

   self.departments(deparmantsData);
   self.selectedDepartment(detailsData.DepartmentId);

});
```

Comment: Thanks! And I didn't know about the deferred object!

Comment: In most cases the performance difference will probably be negligible, but if you want to avoid serializing the requests and allow them both to go to the server simultaneously, then you can add the "dummy" placeholder to your list before the actual list comes in and overwrites it like in: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/BrV6Z/

Answer (score 0):

Knockout tries to enforce that you have made a valid selection based on the current options.  It sounds like sometimes your AJAX request for the selected department returns prior to the list of departments.  In that case, the selected department is not actually in the list of departments.

Some options:

- find a way to make a single request that returns all of the data that you need
- add a dummy entry in your options, if the departments have not been populated yet.  Something like:

  ```
  success: function (data) {
      if (!self.departments().length) {
          self.departments.push(data);
      }
      self.selectedDepartment(data.DepartmentId);
  }
  ```

Then when the departments come in, they can just overwrite this dummy entry.

Comment: That didn't work, what if I put my `GetDetails` ajax call inside the `complete` action of the `GetDepartments` ajax call?

Comment: You can certainly chain them, but that will serialize the requests rather than let both requests go to the server at the same time.  In your case it might not matter much, but the solution that I provided above should work.  If you want to explore it further, then you can try to reproduce your issue from this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/BrV6Z/.